# What is the exact behavior of creeps, on first wave aggro?

Tags: league-of-legends, moba

I am interested in understanding all the creep actions, especially aggro, in League of Legends.

The creeps, you know! The stupid little creatures no one cares about, no one even bothers destroying, which follow a simple path and have very rudimentary combat behavior.

I am adressing this place to know if minion code structure is known in LoL, or in similar MOBA games like HoN, DOTA1&2, Smite, etc.

To be a bit more accurate about my question, I am currently looking for aggro scan specifics, call for help (when a creep draws assistance from an allied creep) prioritization, attack flag structure.

Thanks for answers!

Please note : do not link here the lol wiki minion page, I read it 1000 times :)

Comment: well if you read it 1000 times... what is unclear?

Comment: This is all clear, but too much superficial...

Comment: this is information only a developer could know.

Comment: First of all @DropDeadSander-EUW is right: this is something only a dev could know. second: Mutiple different games might mean different behaviors (Like different aggro priorities etc). This question is far too broad.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ is the right forum to ask this question

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86959/what-is-the-exact-behavior-of-creeps-on-first-wave-aggro-in-league-of-legends
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtEkUmYecnk no offense ;) - I asked there looking for general information about MOBA minions, thought it could help precising the LoL minion patterns.

Comment: there's never a reason to post a question twice on the stackexchange network.

Answer (score 5):

Minions will chose their target by this priotity:

- An enemy champion designated by a call for help from an allied champion. (Enemy champion attacking an Allied champion)
- An enemy minion designated by a call for help from an allied champion. (Enemy minion attacking an Allied champion)
- An enemy minion designated by a call for help from an allied minion. (Enemy minion attacking an Allied minion)
- An enemy turret designated by a call for help from an allied minion. (Enemy turret attacking an Allied minion)
- An enemy champion designated by a call for help from an allied minion. (Enemy champion attacking an Allied minion)
- The closest enemy minion.
- The closest enemy champion.

Comment: This is the basis about LoL minion behaviour indeed, Tier1.

I am looking for Tier2 knowledge, for example, when is call for help issued? is it a code flag? when is it considered answered? what is the accurate aggroscan frequency?

Comment: so... what is unclear? minions are looking for this targets in their range.

Comment: this is information only a developer could know.

Comment: Wether indeed a developer with thick "AI" MOBA knowledge ; or a person whom invested quite a lot of time in such a study :)

Comment: @AlDoubt DropDeadSander isn't referring to just any developer. Only a developer from Riot Games could tell you about implementation details, and they likely won't because it would likely violate a non-disclosure clause in their work contracts.

Comment: @Philipp not really. "any" moba developer could answer this. just like ALDoubt said.

Comment: @DropDeadSander There is no single way to solve this issue. Different MOBAs implement creep behavior in completely differently ways. Present the same problem to 10 different programmers and you get 20 different solutions.

Comment: `in LoL, or in similar MOBA games like HoN, DOTA1&2, Smite, etc.`


read the question.

Comment: @Philipp I discovered today Project Spark, which let you design your game, including MOBA. There is a framework (a "brain") for MOBA minion patterns. I guess you can design quite everything you want from it. Also Riot has ancestors, maybe WC3 DOTA MOD code can be relevant? I do not know well enough the minion behaviors in this game.

Comment: @AlDoubt I'd ask that to the ones who programmed them if I were you, this question is really hard to answer as it's really based on how the developer programmed them. Besides, the code isn't always meant to be shown, and if gamedev didn't get the answer, then the code is actually hidden from the web.

Comment: Tank you all for your answers, I still hope putting together different knowledge from various MOBA users and developers could enlighten this wonder. If not, I guess a question with no answer was definitely a bad question.